# Schematics/Drawings of the Pi Zero?

Tags: hardware, pi-zero

I'm going to try and order a Pi Zero or two (when they are back in stock...), but whilst waiting I would like to design stuff (basic lasercut case etc) so I can use them effectively.

So does anyone know where I can find drawings (both mechanical ([example](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#)) and electrical ([example](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings))) of it? (Also compatibility with previous versions and whether the SoC is equiavlent to a overclocked version of the one on the Pi 1)

What I do know (from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-zero/)):

> - A Broadcom BCM2835 application processor
> - 1GHz ARM11 core (40% faster than Raspberry Pi 1)
> - 512MB of LPDDR2 SDRAM
> - A micro-SD card slot
> - A mini-HDMI socket for 1080p60 video output
> - Micro-USB sockets for data and power
> - An unpopulated 40-pin GPIO header
> - Identical pinout to Model A+/B+/2B
> - An unpopulated composite video header
>
> Our smallest ever form factor, at 65mm x 30mm x 5mm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that not even the schematics of the Pi2 are released I doubt that we will see the electrical design any time soon. (And there might of course be valid concerns at the Foundation to not release them.)

However the mechanical drawings are available at [raspberrpi.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210331161117/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/) in the section *documentation > hardware > raspberrypi > mechanical*.

Comment: LOL I'm unobservant (or they added it afterwards...). Thanks!

Comment: I was going with "they added it afterwards" ^^

Comment: Quick correction: the Raspberry Pi2 schematic is available at https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Raspberry-Pi-R2.0-Schematics-Issue2.2_027.pdf

Comment: @oskarpearson, no, unfortunately not. It's the Revision 2.0 of the Pi 1. Same as is listed in the help > documentation > hardware > raspberrypi > schematics section on raspberrypi.org

Answer (score 4):

To add to Ghanima's answer:

> Also compatibility with previous versions and whether the SoC is equiavlent to a overclocked version of the one on the Pi 1

It is the exact same chip that's in the RPi 1, just clocked faster.  The foundation mentions that in a video on the product's [announcement page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/).  Look at about 1:15 mark.

Comment: Insidious answer to edited question ;) Well, what the heck +1

Comment: @Ghanima - sorry I realized that just asking whether it was the same ARM thing is a stupid question

Comment: @Ghamima: oops. I completely missed the fact that the question had been edited. I thought you were just blind. :P

Comment: lol +1 by the way